# How to show tableau dashboard in a website without prompting for credentials

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tableau-api

We have a website which has dashboards..we analyse data using SQL server analysis services and show it as dashboard using our .net c# code.but now we are changing to tableau..so i want to show the tableau dashboard in place of previous dashboard in our webpage.i have achieved it using embedded code of tableau dashboard.binded it to my aspx page in my website and i have got the result.

But the thing is it is asking credentials while viewing the dashboard.. we are already giving credentials and entering the website.. i don't want another seperate sign in for tableau dashboard..i have googled it have found trusted authentication can help..how to implement it using my c# code using tableau embedded code using single sign on.. kindly help

Comment: Hello Dona, welcome to StackOverlfow. This question is too general and contains too lttle information. Please try to to find the minimal amount of required code that shows the problem and post it here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: K will do that...

Comment: @dona are you using Tableau Public ? (in that case you will not need any login at all)

Comment: No I'm not using tableau public... It's private i think trusted authentication will help

Comment: If using Tableau Server it is possible to set up a "guest" user who does not need to log in so public content can be served if the permission are set appropriately.

Comment: Hi Dona. You have to have core licensing to enable guest users. Core meaning that you have licensing for the number of cores on your server rather than named users. Guests can access content without logging in as matt suggested.